# Mailing passport from South Korea to Canada

Tags: passports, mail

My wife accidentally took my Canadian passport to South Korea and she needs to mail it back. Is it legal to mail passports overseas to my home address (from South Korea to Canada)?

Comment: I don't see why mailing passports would ever be illegal; it's just like any other piece of document. As long as you're fine with mailing it, I don't think anyone would ever object.

Comment: Not even [sending cash is illegal](http://www.snopes.com/legal/postal/sendcash.asp). So yeah, why would passports be?

Comment: @chx DHL/FedEx/UPS won't ship passports internationally between certain countries. Although you can get around their policies by sticking the passport in a thick magazine or a pile of papers.

Comment: @JonathanReez Do you have a source? That sounds very interesting.

Comment: @chx I know from first hand experience that Russia doesn't allow identification documents to be shipped. Other countries might have similar rules.

Comment: I checked DHL's Canada [import guidelines](http://international.dhl.ca/en/country_profile/import_guidelines_express.html) and it doesn't say passports are prohibited, although should check with the "local Customer Service advisor".

Comment: @XuanruiQi You are completely wrong. In some countries it is illegal to send a passport by mail.

Comment: I recently spoke to a traveler who had a family member take their passport to the embassy/consulate to send it as diplomatic mail to the consulate of the country she was in. Inform with both consulates first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Called the Canadian passport services and confirmed mailed passports are illegal. The person said passports had been confiscated at the borders before.

Comment: Presumably, this is specific to Canadian passports. The procedure for renewing a UK passport while living in Canada would not work if they confiscated UK passports at the borders.

Comment: Yes, but in my situation the destination would be to my home address, and not a designated government office. If the mailed passport had a legitimate reason I don't think it would get confiscated.

Comment: Seems odd since Canadian passports can be delivered by post. Maybe internationally is the issue